# Generating Folders based on file names and moving files to a subfolder in the generated folder

Tags: powershell, file, directory, subdirectory

I've managed to create folders based on file names, and moving them in the corresponding folders. But i just cant figure out how to move them in sub folders of the corresponding folders.

Example:

IMG1    Create folder IMG1 and move file to \IMG1\Image\

IMG2    Create folder IMG1 and move file to \IMG2\Image\

IMG3    Create folder IMG1 and move file to \IMG2\Image\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show your current code, sample file names, and the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
$PathToSearch = "C:\Users\mspow\Downloads\Test"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToSearch -File 

foreach ($file in $Files)
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path ($PathToSearch + "\" + $file.BaseName + "\Image")
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination ($PathToSearch + "\" + $file.BaseName + "\Image")
}
```

We use Get-ChildItem to get a list of all files in the directory. Then for each of those files, first we create a new subdirectory in that folder using the Base Name of the file- the name without the extension. Then we move the original file into the new subdirectory.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes that was spot on! Thank you!